# git merge followed by another git merge?

Tags: git, merge

I have an awkward git merge scenario where I am not sure what is the best way forward. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Our development branch has multiple contributors and hence is a hosted git repository. So there are three trees: upstream(say upX), development branch(say devX) & my local git tree for development branch (say local_devX)

As a developer working on devX, I periodically merge changes from upX (aka upstream). Recently the following happened:

1. I merge upstream changes (from upX --> local_devX) and resolve all conflicts. Here is how the trees looked at that point

   ```
   upX:      A---B---C---D---E---F---G
                 |       |           | 
   devX:         --L--M--D'--N--O    |
                                     |  
   local_devX: A--B--L--M--D'--N--O--G'
   ```
2. I begin testing the G' merge which takes about a week (due to bug fixes). Now in the mean time both upstream and local_devX branches have moved forward and I need to resync local_devX branch to accommodate for those changes.

Here is where I am right *now*:

```
    upX:      A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---I
                  |       |           | 
    devX:         --L--M--D'--N--O----|--P--Q
                                      |  
    local_devX: A--B--L--M--D'--N--O--G'
```

I can always blow away my local_devX branch and checkout a fresh copy of devX & do the merge again. But then i will be redoing my merge commit G' all over again.

What would be the best way to achieve the following without having to redo G' work?

```
    upX:      A---B---C---D---E---F---G---H---K
                  |       |                   |
    devX:         --L--M--D'--N--O---P--Q     |
                                              |
    local_devX: A--B--L--M--D'--N--O--P---Q---K'
```

I guess i can do two more merges one for devX changes(P&Q) and the second for upX changes (H&K, since G has already been merge in my local). But I am not sure if this will mess up things like having an unreadable history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with doing one merge after another, or any number of them in a row. It's quite common. Linus Torvalds spends much time these days merging in one commit after another from his dozen or so lieutenants. It works fine.