# Git (Bit Bucket) merge changes from two users to same branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have created a branch in Git (bit bucket). Two persons are modifying same file. One person committed the file. Other person also has local changes in the same file. The second person should be able to merge his code without losing his contents and also the earlier commits should also be intact. I searched many options, but could find a clear reply. Please help me on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git merge followed by another git merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22029872/git-merge-followed-by-another-git-merge)

Answer (score 1):

Git won't allow you (unless you `--force` it) to push a set of commits to a remote branch unless the HEAD of that remote branch is an ancestor of that set of commits.

In other words, if you push, and the other person pushes after you, the other person's push will fail because their commits aren't descendants of your commits. They'll have to `fetch` your change, `rebase` their commits on top of that change (or `merge` it, as an alternative to rebasing) and only then will they be able to push (provided that the remote repo didn't change even more while they were rebasing).

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply.
Does Stash work in this case? The scenario I want to explain is : 
I stash my work before puling from the other user's commits 
stash apply my changes
It merges my changes with the earlier commit, which I can see in my local repo.
Is it correct process? Or there any better ways?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, second person will be able to commit his changes. But before commit he will have to `pull` the changes of the first person. After pulling the changes if there is merge conflict, the second person has to fix the those conflict and then commit. Tips: Working on a same file at the same time is not a good idea. Almost always it creates conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you problem is independent of which git provider use (github, bitbucket, codebase, etc.)

A possible workflow to your case is the following.

There are two developers, **Alice** and **Bob**. Both modified the `parameters.yml`file with next content.

```
# parameters.yml
database_user: 'root'
database_password: 'root'
```

**Alice** adds a parameter to turn on/off the cache.

```
# parameters.yml
database_user: 'root'
database_password: 'root'
cache: true
```

While **Bob** adds other parameter to turn on/off the debug mode in the app.

```
# parameters.yml
database_user: 'root'
database_password: 'root'
debug: false
```

The **Alice** pushes hers changes to `super-cache` branch. After, **Bob** pushes his changes to `super-cache` branch, also. However his push fail because, as @PSkocik said, the **Bob**'s commits are not descendants of **Alice**'s commits.

**Bob** have to fetch the **Alise**'s commits before he pushes his commits. He choices to do a pull with rebase `git pull --rebase origin/super-cache`

**Bob** will have a conflict in `parameters.yml`. The file after resolve the conflict will be

```
# parameters.yml
database_user: 'root'
database_password: 'root'
debug: false
cache: true
```

Now, **Bob** can continue with the merge with `git rebase --continue`

After this, **Bob** have all commits of `super-cache` branch plus his commits.

Finally, **Bob** can push his commits.

You can see: [Git rebase of Atlassian](https://es.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/rewriting-history/git-rebase)